FreehandRasterGeoreferencer
I keep getting an error message related to the Freehand Raster Georeferencer plugin, not necessarily when I first open the project.
TypeError: invalid result from FreehandRasterGeoreferencerLayer.metadata(), str cannot be converted to qgis._core.QgsLayerMetadata in this context
I deleted all raster layers but as soon as I add one, this starts up again.
It's been happening since 3:34 and now on 3.38.
Any ideas?

Further to this I see now that it when I open a raster layer (or group of layers containing a raster) that this error occurs sometimes immediately sometimes after a few minutes. It is not one specific raster, but any one in the project. If I do not load any rasters, I do not get the error.
